# Request.Headers["Referer"] does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a solution with two ASP.NET Core MVC projects. One project (`Client`) is making a request to the other (`Server`) using `HttpClient`. When the action in `Server` receives the request, I want to get the URL of the thing that sent it. Every article I have read purports `Request.Headers["Referer"]` as the solution, but in my case `Headers` does not contain a "referer" key (or "referrer").

When receiving the request in `Server`, how should I find the URL of the `Client` that sent it?

Answer (score 3):

That is how you you get the referring url for a request.  But the referer isn't the thing that sent the request.  The referer gets set in the headers by the browser when a person clicks on a link from one website to go to another website.  When that request is made by the browser to the new website the request will typically have the Referer header which will contain the url of the prior website.

The receiving server can't get the url of the "client" making the request, remember a typical web browser client isn't at any url.  All the receiving server can get is the IP address of the client typically.

Since you have control of the client software, if you wanted you could have the client put whatever info you want in the header of the request before it's sent to the server and the server could then get that info out of the header.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `HttpClient`, then it is up to the site *making the request* to add that header. It isn't added automatically in this case. So: change the code - or request that the code is changed - so as to add the header and value that you expect. If you are proxying through a request, you might get the value from the *current request's* `Referer` header, and add that.

---

Even in the general case of a *browser* making the request as part of a normal page cycle, you can't rely on it: the `Referer` header is often deliberately not sent; depending on the browser version, configuration, whether you're going between different domains, whether it is HTTPS or not,  and `rel` markers on a `<a href=...` such as "noreferrer".